# Long-running polling application incorrectly marked "Not Responding" in Activity Monitor

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, itunes

I have a tiny Objective-C application that runs in the background, polling iTunes for the current track every 2 seconds, which writes my play history to a file in my home directory. (Unfortunately, polling is the only way to collect iTunes history if you're not iTunes.)

It gets started as a Login Item and performs beautifully, even if I quit and restart iTunes, but it consistently shows up as `(Not Responding)` in Activity Monitor.app, highlighted red:

[image: Activity Monitor screenshot]

The app is still working, logging to file as expected, no problems there, but I would like for it to be reported correctly in Activity Monitor. Is there some magic Cocoa / Objective-C flag that I can set to inform OS X that my app is running via `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]` + repeating `NSTimer` and not going to be as responsive as OS X seems to expect?

For reference, the application in question is on GitHub: [chbrown/iTunesHistory](https://github.com/chbrown/iTunesHistory/blob/master/iTunesHistory.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHistory.m)

Comment: are you blocking the main thread?

Comment: @Sulthan I'm not sure. Is `NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]; [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; [runLoop run];` blocking the main thread?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does. Why do you call `run` for the main loop? Isn't it already running?

Comment: The main thread is running, but the loop is not, and the program exits immediately unless I call `[runLoop run]`. This got me thinking back to the NSRunLoop docs, and so I also just tried using `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` instead of `[.. mainRunLoop]`, which works just as well, but suffers from the same "Not Responding" misrepresentation in Activity Monitor.